# AWS S3 returns 404 for a file that definitely still exists there

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We have some code that downloads a bunch of S3 files to a local directory. The list of files to retrieve is from a query we run. It only lists files that actually exist in our S3 bucket.

As we loop to retrieve these files, about 10% of them return a 404 error as if the file doesn't exist. I log out the name/location of that file, so I can go to S3 and check, and sure enough every single one of the IS ON S3 in the location we went looking for it.

Why does S3 throw a 404 when the file exists?

Here is the Groovy code of the script.

```
class RetrieveS3FilesFromCSVLoader implements Loader {

private static String missingFilesFile = "00-MISSED_FILES.csv"
private static String csvFileName = "/csv/s3file2.csv"
private static String saveFilesToLocation = "/tmp/retrieve/"

public static final char SEPARATOR = ','

@Autowired
DocumentFileService documentFileService

private void readWithCommaSeparatorSQL() {

    int counter = 0
    String fileName
    String fileLocation
    File missedFiles = new File(saveFilesToLocation + missingFilesFile)
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(missedFiles)
    File fileCSV = new File(getClass().getResource(csvFileName).toURI())

    fileCSV.splitEachLine(SEPARATOR as String) { nextLine ->
        //if (counter < 15) {
            if (nextLine != null && (nextLine[0] != 'FileLocation')) {
                counter++
                try {
                    //Remove 0, only if client number start with "0".
                    fileLocation = nextLine[0].trim()

                    byte[] fileBytes = documentFileService.getFile(fileLocation)
                    if (fileBytes != null) {
                        fileName = fileLocation.substring(fileLocation.indexOf("/") + 1, fileLocation.length())
                        File file = new File(saveFilesToLocation + fileName)
                        file.withOutputStream {
                            it.write fileBytes
                        }
                        println "$counter) Wrote file ${fileLocation} to ${saveFilesToLocation + fileLocation}"
                    } else {
                        println "$counter) UNABLE TO RETRIEVE FILE ELSE: $fileLocation"
                        writer.println(fileLocation)
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    println "$counter) UNABLE TO RETRIEVE FILE: $fileLocation"
                    println(e.getMessage())
                    writer.println(fileLocation)
                }
            } else {
                counter++;
            }
        //}
    }
    writer.close()
}
```

Here is the code for getFile(fileLocation) and client creation.

```
public byte[] getFile(String filename) throws IOException {
    AmazonS3Client s3Client = connectToAmazonS3Service();
    S3Object object = s3Client.getObject(S3_BUCKET_NAME, filename);
    if(object == null) {
        return null;
    }
    byte[] fileAsArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(object.getObjectContent());
    object.close();

    return fileAsArray;
}

/**
 * Connects to Amazon S3
 *
 * @return instance of AmazonS3Client
 */
private AmazonS3Client connectToAmazonS3Service() {
    AWSCredentials credentials;
    try {
        credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID, S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AmazonClientException(
                "Cannot load the credentials from the credential profiles file. " +
                        "Please make sure that your credentials file is at the correct " +
                        "location (~/.aws/credentials), and is in valid format.",
                e);
    }

    AmazonS3Client s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
    Region usWest2 = Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1);
    s3.setRegion(usWest2);

    return s3;
}
```

The code above works for 90% of the files in the list passed to the script, but we know with fact that all 100% of the files exist in S3 and with the location String we are passing.

Comment: are the files very recently `PUT` into the bucket by another process -- or is the list command retrieving files that have existed in the bucket for some time where they couldn't suffer from read after write visibility?

Comment: These have been in S3 for months. And in our actual app I can get the files. So the downloader script that has the issue is using the same download code for individual files previewer as being used in our app.

Comment: Can you post a little bit of code with the loop and the `AmazonS3Client` usage?

Comment: @DaveMaple I've added code, but I don't think that will help. As I said that code is used in our app and for all the files in the list, from the app will preview for us. In the script with the list of file locations (All using the same data that that app used and Strings in the file are 100% accurate) 

In the script it is random files that fail, and only a handful. None of them should fail though. It is one of those hair pulling out issue for me. ;)

Comment: `Region usWest2 = Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)` -- is us-east-1 correct or is that supposed to be west2?

Comment: Thanks @DaveMaple Yes it is correct, the variable name doesn't matter as I have said this code works 100% of the time in the app for the files, but only 90% when ran from the script. We only use US_EAST_1. The original coder named the variable wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I am just an idiot. Thought it had the production AWS credentials in the properties file. Instead it was development credentials. So I had the wrong credentials.